# ImportError: No module named 'Crypto.HASH' but pycryto installed

Tags: python-3.x, pycrypto

I am trying to load pycrypto module. When I do

```
import Crypto
```

I get no error but when I do from `Crypto.HASH import SHA256` , I am getting `ImportError`

```
>>> import Crypto
>>> hash = SHA256.new()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    hash = SHA256.new()
NameError: name 'SHA256' is not defined
>>> from Crypto.HASH import SHA256
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    from Crypto.HASH import SHA256
ImportError: No module named 'Crypto.HASH'
>>>
```

OS : Windows 8
Python : 3.5 32 Bit

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misspelling it, the correct module name is `Crypto.Hash`:

```
>>> from Crypto.Hash import SHA256
>>> h=SHA256.new()
>>> h.update(b"Hello")
>>> h.hexdigest()
'185f8db32271fe25f561a6fc938b2e264306ec304eda518007d1764826381969'
```

Comment: Next time just flag to close or vote to close the question as off-topic, because this is a typo and will probably not be helpful to future readers.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Okay, I will consider this in the future.